# Why do print(()) and input(()) print parentheses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, output

I was playing around with `input(())` and noticed that it printed a pair of parens as the prompt. I figured it was because it took something as an argument to make a prompt. However, I have to put other things in quotes if I want to make them the prompt.

I then tried out `print(())` and got the same behavior (so I presume input just passes its arg to print). Why are parentheses special in that they don't need to be in quotes?

Comment: Because `()` is an empty tuple. `print(())` prints the tuple.

Comment: You can print any object, `print([])` doesn't require quotes either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`()` is an empty tuple:

```
>>> t = ()
>>> t
()
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> print(t)
()
```

Both `input()` and `print()` convert their argument(s) to string before printing. There is nothing special about a tuple here, you can do the same with other objects:

```
>>> print({'a', 'set', 'object'})
{'object', 'a', 'set'}
>>> input({'a', 'set', 'object'})
{'object', 'a', 'set'}
```